# Using different fonts within the same axis title

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a plot according to nature guidelines. The rules state that all text must be in Arial/Helvetica but greek letters must be in the symbol font. Is there any way of making my axis title in Arial and the units in symbol font without manually adding 2 different text elements? Here is my code for reference.

```
ggplot(aes(
  x = fct_inorder(Dose),
  y = fct_rev(fct_inorder(Tissue_type)),
  fill = viability,
)) +
  geom_tile(color = "black") +
  xlab(label = "Dose of AC484 (\u03bcM)") +
  ylab(label = "") +
  theme_void() +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(
      size = 3.59, angle = 45, hjust = 1.0, margin = margin(t = -11, b = 0),
      family = "Arial", color = "#000000", vjust = 0.75
    ),
    axis.title.x = element_text(
      size = 3.59, family = "Arial", color = "black", vjust = -3.5,
      margin = margin(t = 2, b = 5)
    )
  )
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data best shared via `dput()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your desired result using the `ggtext` package which adds advanced text rendering support to `ggplot2` and allows to style text using a limited amount of HTML/CSS and markdown. For your present text you can wrap the text for which you want a different font family inside a `<span>` tag and set the font family via CSS. Additionally you have to switch to `ggtext::element_markdown` for the respective theme element. Additionally I refactored your `theme()` adjustments slightly. Most of the time time there are better ways then setting vjust/hjust  to values outside of the supported range of 0 to 1 or margins to negative values. This is bad practice and should be avoided except for rare cases.

Note: I have set the font size for the Symbol font to 20pt as otherwise a difference compared to Arial is hardly visible.

Using a reproducible example based on mtcars:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)
library(forcats)

dat <- mtcars |>
  dplyr::mutate(
    across(c(cyl, am), factor)
  ) |>
  dplyr::summarise(viability = mean(mpg), .by = c(cyl, am)) |>
  dplyr::rename(
    Dose = cyl, Tissue_type = am
  )

dat |>
  ggplot(aes(
    x = fct_inorder(Dose),
    y = fct_rev(fct_inorder(Tissue_type)),
    fill = viability,
  )) +
  geom_tile(color = "black") +
  xlab(
    label = paste0(
      "Dose of AC484 (",
      "<span style='font-family: Symbol; font-size: 20pt'>\u03bcM</span>)"
    )
  ) +
  ylab(label = NULL) +
  theme_void() +
  coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE) +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(
      size = 8, angle = 45, hjust = 1,
      family = "Arial", color = "#000000",
      vjust = 1,
      margin = margin(t = 2.5, b = 0)
    ),
    axis.title.x = ggtext::element_markdown(
      size = 8, family = "Arial", color = "black",
      margin = margin(t = 2.5)
    ),
    plot.margin = margin(5.5, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5)
  )
```

[image]